# Certbot issue DNS problem: NXDOMAIN looking up TXT for _acme-challenge.mydomain.click

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl-certificate, amazon-route53, lets-encrypt, certbot

I followed [this](https://certbot-dns-route53.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) guide step by step to generate certificates for my domain (mydomain.click) which is managed by route53.

I created an IAM user with the following permissions:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "certbot-dns-route53 sample policy",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "route53:ListHostedZones",
                "route53:GetChange"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect" : "Allow",
            "Action" : [
                "route53:ChangeResourceRecordSets"
            ],
            "Resource" : [
                "arn:aws:route53:::hostedzone/aed763ejfgasfja"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Then I configured the access and secret key of this user on one of the VM where certbot is installed.

Finally, I ran this command to get the certificates:

```
certbot certonly --dns-route53 -d mydomain.click
```

It return the following error:

```
root@ip-192-168-19-189:/tmp# certbot certonly --dns-route53 -d mydomain.click
Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log
Requesting a certificate for mydomain.click
Certbot failed to authenticate some domains (authenticator: dns-route53). The Certificate Authority reported these problems:
  Domain: mydomain.click
  Type:   dns
  Detail: DNS problem: NXDOMAIN looking up TXT for _acme-challenge.mydomain.click - check that a DNS record exists for this domain

Hint: The Certificate Authority failed to verify the DNS TXT records created by --dns-route53. Ensure the above domains are hosted by this DNS provider, or try increasing --dns-route53-propagation-seconds (currently 10 seconds).

Some challenges have failed.
Ask for help or search for solutions at https://community.letsencrypt.org. See the logfile /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log or re-run Certbot with -v for more details.
```

I understand that some TXT records need to be created in route53 but what value needs to be entered in that entry? Am I missing any critical step here?

Answer (score 1):

Have you verified that the DNS records are being created? I had to explicitly set the propagation seconds to allow more time for the DNS records to propagate and resolve. Your IAM policy looks correct.

```
certbot certonly --force-renew --dns-route53 --dns-route53-propagation-seconds 20
```

Comment: getting the same error using the above command. While the command is running, I refreshed the AWS dashboard and found that a TXT record was created, but then it got deleted and the verification failed for the command :(

Comment: If the DNS record has been created, then this is not a permissions issue with AWS. Have you tried setting the propagation seconds to something very long (300 secs)?

Also I note the shell prompt in your example suggests the server where you are running certbot is not on AWS. What are you using for a DNS server in resolv.conf, and is that the potential failure point? You could try public DNS servers like 8.8.8.8, 4.2.2.2, etc. instead of local servers, and that may uncover any issues with propagation time.